# How to get at instance variable in rake task for testing in rspec 3.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So I have a rake task:

```
task :some_task do
  # some stuff
  @myvar = 2
  SomeModel.my_method
end
```

I have the rspec test setup such that I can tell if SomeModel calls my method, but how do I check if instance variable @myvar is set to 2?  I tried moving it outside the task block but to no avail.  I'm using RSpec 3.4 with Rails 4.2.x and Ruby 2.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

In `SomeModel` add an `attr_accessor` for the `@myvar` instance variable.

Eg:

```
class SomeModel
    attr_accessor :myvar

    def my_method
        @myvar = 2
    end
end
```

Now you can access it

```
task :some_task do
  # some stuff
  # @myvar = 2

  SomeModel.myvar = 3
  SomeModel.my_method

  assert_match SomeModel.myvar, 2

end
```